# Error in deploying a SvelteKit app to Firebase - upstream dependency conflict

Tags: firebase, npm, firebase-hosting, sveltekit, pnpm

I have a sveltekit project that I try to upload to Firebase hosting with their new webframework support, but keep getting the following error (I have checked question [How to host a sveltekit app with firebase hosting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74444562/how-to-host-a-sveltekit-app-with-firebase-hosting) , but it is not the new feature):

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: firebase-frameworks@0.10.5
npm ERR! Found: firebase@10.0.0
npm ERR! node_modules/firebase
npm ERR!   firebase@"10.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peerOptional firebase@"^9.9.0" from firebase-frameworks@0.10.5
npm ERR! node_modules/firebase-frameworks
npm ERR!   firebase-frameworks@"^0.10.4" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: firebase@9.23.0
npm ERR! node_modules/firebase
npm ERR!   peerOptional firebase@"^9.9.0" from firebase-frameworks@0.10.5
npm ERR!   node_modules/firebase-frameworks
npm ERR!     firebase-frameworks@"^0.10.4" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-07-21T13_30_08_813Z-eresolve-report.txt

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-07-21T13_30_08_813Z-debug-0.log
```

I know this feature is experimental, so what I do is :

```
firebase experiments:enable webframeworks
firebase init hosting
```

The project builds succesfully:

```
<build happens here>
Run npm run preview to preview your production build locally.

> Using @sveltejs/adapter-auto
  Could not detect a supported production environment. See https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/adapters to learn how to configure your app to run on the platform of your choosing
  ✔ done
✓ built in 9.15s
```

This was working few weeks ago, but fails now. i tried to go with pnpm (since yarn does not play well with sveltekit) but it did not work either.

My package.json file is as follows:

```
{
    "name": "<name>",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "vite dev",
        "build": "vite build",
        "preview": "vite preview",
        "check": "svelte-kit sync && svelte-check --tsconfig ./tsconfig.json",
        "check:watch": "svelte-kit sync && svelte-check --tsconfig ./tsconfig.json --watch",
        "lint": "prettier --plugin-search-dir . --check . && eslint .",
        "format": "prettier --plugin-search-dir . --write ."
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@sveltejs/adapter-auto": "^2.0.0",
        "@sveltejs/kit": "^1.20.4",
        "@tailwindcss/typography": "^0.5.9",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.45.0",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.45.0",
        "autoprefixer": "^10.4.14",
        "daisyui": "^3.2.1",
        "eslint": "^8.28.0",
        "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
        "eslint-plugin-svelte": "^2.30.0",
        "postcss": "^8.4.25",
        "prettier": "^2.8.0",
        "prettier-plugin-svelte": "^2.10.1",
        "svelte": "^4.0.0",
        "svelte-check": "^3.4.3",
        "tailwindcss": "^3.3.2",
        "tslib": "^2.4.1",
        "typescript": "^5.0.0",
        "vite": "^4.3.6"
    },
    "type": "module",
    "dependencies": {
        "firebase": "^10.0.0",
        "firebase-admin": "^11.9.0"
    }
}
```

My firebase.json file is as follows:

```
{
  "functions": [
    {
      "source": "functions",
      "codebase": "default",
      "ignore": [
        "node_modules",
        ".git",
        "firebase-debug.log",
        "firebase-debug.*.log"
      ],
      "predeploy": [
        "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint",
        "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run build"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "firestore": {
    "rules": "firestore.rules",
    "indexes": "firestore.indexes.json"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "source": ".",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "frameworksBackend": {
      "region": "europe-west1"
    }
  },
  "storage": {
    "rules": "storage.rules"
  }
}
```

I tried to use yarn, it did not work at all. I tried pnpm, I got the same error. I tried to change the versions of the dependencies, that did not work, either. I  tried to find the `firebase-frameworks@0.10.5` package in the .lock file, it was not there.
I was expecting to get a deployment to firebase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem here, I changed the dependencies in the package.json as follow

```
"dependencies": {
        "firebase": "^9.23.0",
        "firebase-admin": "^11.10.1",
        "firebase-frameworks": "0.10.4"
    }
```

and it let me deploy to Firebase.

Hope it helps

Comment: Actually, after that change, I had to:
rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json
and
npm install

and make sure of using node version 18 (I was using 20 and did no let me deploy)

Comment: Thank you, this finally works. You're right; the experimental Firebase feature only supports NodeJS major version 18; the current version 20 is incompatible. Therefore it may be a good idea to use nvm for different node versions.